# Can I see my new git commits in a new TestFlight build if I have unresolved issues from Apple Store Connect?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, testflight

A few days ago I successfully delivered Version 1.0.0 Build 1 of my new app to TestFlight. I then made some updates to my code and updated everything to my Github repo's master branch. When I attempted to deliver a new build of my app. I received this email...

"Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "AppName" 1.0.0 (2). Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:

ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - details...

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - details...

After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect.

Best regards,
The App Store Team"

My new build (Build 2) was accessible a few minutes later via TestFlight, however I'm not seeing any of the new changes I made. I then tried another build where I incremented my Version number as well as my Build number, but that didn't do anything either.

So my question is: Do I have to fix these issues before I can see any new updates to my app?

Comment: No, the new build is appearing and it is the build you are delivering. Apple doesn't know anything about your source control system. If it doesn't contain the changes then there is an issue with the code you are archiving.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for your response! Now I just have to figure out what's wrong with the code I'm archiving...